# How is $\sum_{i=0}^{\log n -1} 2^i(\log n -i) =\sum_{i=1}^{\log n} i\frac n {2^i} $

Tags: summation, logarithms

I found the following in a textbook: $$\sum_{i=0}^{\log n -1} 2^i(\log n -i) =\sum_{i=1}^{\log n} i\frac n {2^i} $$

It's a summation of a chart, the explanation for this was to "flip the chart", I don't see it in the chart, I also don't see a way to do this algebriacly, how is it even possible to cancel out the $\log n -i$?

Note: Here $\log n = \log _2 n$

Comment: *Assuming $\log$ is $\log_2$ and $\log n$ is an integer*, consider $j=\log n-i$, then $1\leqslant j\leqslant\log n$ and $2^i(\log n-i)=jn/2^j$, as needed.

Comment: Ah, change of parameter like with integrals, I completely forgot about this.