# Solving $\sum_{i=0} ^{\log n} i2^i$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, asymptotics

> Solve (or simplify): $$\sum_{i=0} ^{\log n} i2^i$$ (without integrals)

Trying to change the parameter: $j=i2^i$, so since $ 0\le i \le \log n$, then the maximum value for $j$ is when $j=n\log n$. So we get $ \displaystyle \sum_{i=0} ^{\log n} i2^i = \sum_{j=0} ^{n\log n} j$

Now I can use the formula to get $ \displaystyle \sum_{j=0} ^{nlog n} j = \Theta ((n \log n)^2)$ but it doesn't seem right when I compare it with a series calculator.

Maybe did I get the upper bound wrong?

PS: Here: $\log n = \log _2 n$

Comment: You can't just change the parameter like that. A different idea is to actually compute $\sum_{i=0}^m i 2^i$ for general $m$. It has an explicit formula. One way to do it is to write $\sum_{i=1}^m i 2^i = \sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^i 2^i = \sum_{j=1}^m \sum_{i=j}^m 2^i$, then use the formula for the geometric series on the inside.

Comment: @Ian why not? It's like changing paremeters with integrals no? I also saw this in a recent question of mine: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1617121/how-is-sum-i-0-log-n-1-2i-log-n-i-sum-i-1-log-n-i-frac-n-2i

Comment: To actually change the parameter you would need to match each number $i 2^i$ with a number between $0$ and $n \log n$, which does not really change the problem at all. You wind up with a sum where a bunch of terms are zero and a bunch of terms are $j$, and you need to work with the zero pattern to evaluate the sum. This is perhaps even harder than the original sum.

Comment: What is the nature of index $i$? How many terms have your sum?

Comment: @Ian I think I understand, spliting the sum like that is a nice trick.

Comment: @ian why did the upper bound change from i to m?

Comment: @kuhaku You add up $f(i,j)$ for $i=1,\dots,m$ and $1 \leq j \leq i$. So you always have $j \leq i$, which means you always have $i \geq j$. This gets reflected in the new limits after interchanging the summation. This makes more sense if you draw a picture (we are summing elements of a triangular array by rows vs. by columns).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^{n}i \cdot 2^{i} &= 2+(4+4)+(8+8+8)+\ldots+(\underbrace{ 2^{n}+2^{n}+\ldots+2^{n}}_{n\text{ times}})\\
&=(2+4+8+\ldots+2^{n-1}+2^{n})+(4+8+\ldots+2^{n-1}+2^{n})+(8+\ldots\\
&\quad+2^{n-1}+2^{n})+\ldots+(2^{n-2}+2^{n-1}+2^{n})+(2^{n-1}+2^{n})+2^{n}\\
&=2(1+2+4+\ldots+2^{n-2}+2^{n-1})+4(1+2+4+\ldots+2^{n-3}+2^{n-2})+8(1+\ldots\\
& \quad+2^{n-3})+\ldots+2^{n-2}(1+2+4)+2^{n-1}(1+2)+2^{n}\\
&=2(2^{n}-1)+4(2^{n-1}-1)+8(2^{n-2}-1)+\ldots+2^{n-2}(2^{3}-1)+2^{n-1}(2^{2}-1)+2^{n}\\
&= (n-1)2^{n+1}+2^{n}-2-4-\ldots-2^{n-1}=(n-1)2^{n+1}+2^{n}-2(2^{n-1}-1)\\
&= (n-1)2^{n+1}+2\\
&= 2(2^n(n-1) + 1)
\end{align}

thus, assuming that $\log n = \log_2 n$, you get
$$\sum_{i=0} ^{\log n} i2^i = 2(1+2^{\log n}(\log n-1)) = 2(1+n(\log n-1))$$

Comment: which is rather less than $\displaystyle  \sum_{j=0} ^{n\log n} j =\dfrac{n \log_2 n \,(n \log_2 n -1)}{2}$

Comment: "$\sum_{i=0} ^{n} i2^i = 2(1+2^n(n-1))$" how did you get that?

Comment: edited to add proof

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the change in parameter is done poorly. If you write out the first few terms, you see that your parameter change changes the sum.

Try the following instead: Let $f_k(x)=\sum_{i=0}^k x^{i+1}$. Then $$f'_k(x)=\sum_{i=0}^k (i+1)x^i=\sum_{i=0}^k ix^i+\sum_{i=0}^k x^i$$

Substitute in the explicit formula for $\sum_{i=0}^k x^i$, calculate the derivative on the LHS, and simplify. Then plug in $\log(n)$ and $2$

Comment: Your definition of $f$ has no $x$ in it. I assume you want $\sum_{i=0}^k x^{i+1}$ then differentiate and substitute $x=2$.

Comment: @Ian Oh yes, thank you. Fixed

Answer (score 0):

Take into account that $$\sum_{i=0} ^{x} i2^i = x 2^{x + 1} - 2^{x + 1} + 2$$ and put $x = \log_{2} n$ to get $$2 (\log_{2} n - 1) n + 2.$$